# math.random unexpected symbol error

Tags: lua, coronasdk

Im trying to increase math.random over time by using this code:

```
testa = 100
testb = 150

badclouts:setLinearVelocity(0, math.random(.. testa, .. testb)) -- Drop down

local function speatTimer()
   testa = testa+1
   testb = testb+1
   --print("testa " .. testa)
   --print("testb " .. testb)
end
local mainTimer = timer.performWithDelay( 1000, speatTimer, 500 )
```

But getting a 'unexpected symbol' error on **badclouts:setLinearVelocity(0, math.random(.. testa, .. testb)) -- Drop down**

How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just remove the two instances of `..` in the call to `badclouts:setLinearVelocity`.